# Installings latest imagemagick with LCMS on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, imagemagick, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

We are using AWS (beanstalk) to host an application that does heavy image processing.
Recently we discovered that we need to convert color profiles and for that it seems that ImageMagick needs to be compiled with some special LCMS support.

For now we are using a standard ImageMagick package that amazon provides, we just put the following in .ebextentions/xxx.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    ImageMagick: []
    git: []
```

Is there any way to install a different version of ImageMagick with LCMS support without compiling it ourselves and then maintaining our own AMI for this, I would really like to avoid that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own commands in the `commands` section or you can even have entire scripts run. You could easily pull down the source yourself and compile with the `--with-lcms=yes` flag.

An example of the commands section looks like this:

```
commands:
    command1:
        command: echo "this will run"
    command2:
        command: echo "this will run too"
```

Documentation on that can be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-commands

Comment: This is load balanced environment with more nodes being added automatically when there is a spike in the amount of pics to be processed. If nodes will compile image magic during deployment that will defeat the purpose of adding them in the first place :) I was more looking for a trick that would allow me to refer yam to another package that has everything in.

Comment: If you don't want the overhead of creating a new AMI, you could always look at Docker which is supported by Elastic Beanstalk. It shouldn't be too hard to create a Docker image with Imagemagick compiled to your liking.

Comment: To add to @JoshDavis answer, you could also compile your own version of ImageMagick and store it in your S3 bucket. You can then download the rpm from your S3 bucket using the ebextension commands and install it on the EC2 instances during the deployment.

Comment: @RohitBanga's answer is the best route to take. It'll probably be the simplest and fastest.